# Extract hashtags from entities and add them to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, sentiment-analysis

I created the following dataframe from a json tweets file.

```
tweets['text'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data))
tweets['date'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['created_at'], tweets_data))
tweets['lang'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweets_data))
tweets['place_type'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['place_type'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data))
tweets['place_name'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['full_name'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data))
tweets['country'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data))
tweets['hashtags'] =  list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['entities']['hashtags'], tweets_data))
```

The current output of the hashtags column is the following:

```
"[{'text': 'NOJUSTICE', 'indices': [62, 72]}, {'text': 'TrumpPence', 'indices': [93, 104]}]"
```

I'm trying to create a new column that only contains the hashtags. For example:

NOJUSTICE and Trumpence

I tried the following code:

```
ht=[]
for s in range(len(tweets['hashtags'])):
    hasht=[]
    for t in range(len(tweets.hashtags[s])):
        hasht.append(tweets['hashtags'][s][t]['text'])
        t=t+1
    ht.append(hasht)
    s=s+1
tweets['HT']=zip(ht)
```

and I received the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-9780008354d7> in <module>
      3     hasht=[]
      4     for t in range(len(tweets.hashtags[s])):
----> 5         hasht.append(tweets['hashtags'][s][t]['text'])
      6         t=t+1
      7     ht.append(hasht)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

[sample csv file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1e8b0af1332f0b31fa12c957ed334dd520190918223501/f66510)

i want the hashtags column to only contain the hashtags without the indices and other stuff

UPDATE: i used the following suggestion and got the same error

```
tweets['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: [d['text'] for d in x])
```

Comment: Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: @BMW i added a sample csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) to parse the hashtag as follows:

```
tweets['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: [d['text'] for d in x])
```

Then you need to store the output in a new column of the dataframe. This anonymous function takes the value as input and iterates over each dictionary in the list (if it's non empty), then creates a new list of the values in key: 'text'. The output would look like this:

```
0                                                  []
1                             [NOJUSTICE, TrumpPence]
2                                                  []
3                                                  []
4                          [CNN, newday, Trump, ISIS]
5                                        [NeverTrump]
6    [Trump2016, TrumpPence16, MakeAmericaGreatAgain]
7                                                  []
8                                                  []
9                                                  []
dtype: object
```

Comment: currently i have a column called hashtags for each tweet in my dataframe. and one of the tweets has the hashtags in the question. im trying to create a new column that only has the hashtags